# JQuery Mobile Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm getting the error with this code, specifically the if statement, in the jquery mobile script...

```
parseUrl: function (url) {
// If we're passed an object, we'll assume that it is
// a parsed url object and just return it back to the caller.
if ($.type(url) === "object") {
```

$.type is not a function it's saying; any idea why?  I have jquery 1.7 referenced too and it's above the JQuery Mobile script.

Comment: Have you had any other library included in your project other than jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Reminder: 1.0 will ship with jQuery core 1.6.4**
>
> Since 1.7 was just recently released and has some significant changes
>   (and improvements), we are going to be supporting only 1.6.4 when
>   jQuery Mobile 1.0 is released. We plan on adding 1.7 support when we
>   release version 1.1 so please remember that 1.7 is not supported at
>   this time.

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/13/jquery-mobile-rc3-released/

Comment: I didn't realize; I'll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice to know. Let us know if this is the cause of your issue and fixes it, @Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the jQuery library before your jQuery mobile js files? The jQuery.min.js file has to come first.

You could also test by using the following. If it doesn't work then the jQuery lib has not been loaded yet:

```
jQuery.type( obj ) === "object"
```

Comment: The jquery script is first.  I tested with $.attr, $.ajax, and those are present.